# int var getting bizarre values

Tags: c, gcc, int

Int value 'j' is getting weird results when i keep trying to debug it. I'm not sure if it's a problem with my school's compiler or if it's my code. Thanks for the help.

*GCC Version:
Reading specs from /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.7/2.95.2/specs
gcc version 2.95.2 19991024 (release)*

My segment of code that's messing up:

```
    void sFlag(DIR * dirp, int c, char *dirname)
    {
        struct dirent *dp;
        struct stat statbuf;
        struct stat statarray[c];
        struct stat tempstat;
        char fullfilename[MAXSZ];
        int i;
        int boo; 
        int j; /*<--------- variable that's messing up*/

        while((dp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
        {
            snprintf(fullfilename, MAXSZ, "%s/%s", dirname, dp->d_name);
            if(stat(fullfilename, &statbuf) == -1)
                printf("Could not read file %s\n", dp->d_name);
            else if(isHiddenFile(dp->d_name))
            {
                statarray[i] = statbuf;
                i++;
            }
        }
/*As far as i know all the code above works fine*/

 /*bubble sort that will sort array by logical file size*/
        while(boo)
        {
            j = 0;
            boo = 0;
            while(j < c)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", j);  /*print debug info*/
                if(statarray[j].st_size < statarray[j+1].st_size)
                {
                    tempstat = statarray[j];
                    statarray[j] = statarray[j+1];
                    statarray[j+1] = tempstat;
                    boo = 1;
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            printf("%s\t%ld\t%s\n", dp->d_name, statarray[j].st_size, ctime(&statarray[j].st_mtime));
        }   
    }
```

So everytime i run this the fprintf prints out the value for j as:
0
1
2
3
4
-12975991
???????Where did it get that number from??? 
Obviously I get a segmentation fault from an array index out of bounds

any thoughts?

Comment: `while(j < c)` and then `statarray[j+1]`.  That is wrong.  What happens when `j == c - 1`?  You index one past the bounds of `statearray`.

Comment: I'm surprised that you did not notice the out-of-bounds index when you ran you code under your debugger and stepped through.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys, yeah when i had j at the last value it was trying to access statarray[5] which was out of bounds and was messing the values up. changed it to j<c-1 and now at least that segment of the ode works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely trampling memory and overwriting the content of `j`. This loop:

```
        while(j < c)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", j);  /*print debug info*/
            if(statarray[j].st_size < statarray[j+1].st_size)
            {
                tempstat = statarray[j];
                statarray[j] = statarray[j+1];
                statarray[j+1] = tempstat;
                boo = 1;
            }
            j++;
        }
```

Notice that it accesses `statarray[j+1]`, but `statarray` is defined as

```
    struct stat statarray[c];
```

meaning that on the last iteration, `j+1 == c`, which is out of bounds. Writing to that index in the array will trample other things on the stack, which could include `j`, and explain why you get a wacky-sounding value.

There are some nifty tools that can make this easier to find that you might consider, like `valgrind`.

Answer (score 1):

In this block,

```
        while(j < c)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", j);  /*print debug info*/
            if(statarray[j].st_size < statarray[j+1].st_size)
            {
                tempstat = statarray[j];
                statarray[j] = statarray[j+1];
                statarray[j+1] = tempstat;
                boo = 1;
            }
            j++;
        }
```

You are accessing unauthorized memory when `j` is equal to `c-1`. That would mess things up. You can't expect predictable behavior after that.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fresh variable `j` in the `while` loop, the outer `j` is never set.